# Is there a way to do multiselect in ObjectListView without the Ctrl key pressed?

Tags: c#, multi-select, objectlistview

I set the FullRowSelect and MultiSelect property to true in the ObjectListView component, but I still have to select multiple rows by pressing the Ctrl key. So, Is there a way to do multiselect without the Ctrl or shift key pressed?

Comment: Interesting question. I am pretty sure this isn't supported natively. And I think its not so easy to implement. If you don't want to mess with the OLV code, one approach would probably be to handle some event that the selection changed, keep track of previously selected items and re-select them programatically after the selection ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a working solution. The model objects in this example are of type "Item". For some explanations see code comments.

```
// We require a list to remember which items should stay selected
private List<Item> _MultiSelectList;

public Form1() {
    // <other stuff>
    _MultiSelectList = new List<Item>();
}

// use this event to check which item has been clicked
private void objectListView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    objectListView1.BeginUpdate();

    // any item clicked?
    if (objectListView1.MouseMoveHitTest.Item != null) {
        var item = objectListView1.MouseMoveHitTest.Item.RowObject as Item;

        // model object of expected type available?
        if (item != null) {
            // add or remove item from list to effectively toggle selection
            if (_MultiSelectList.Contains(item)) {
                _MultiSelectList.Remove(item);
            } else {
                _MultiSelectList.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    // select all desired items
    objectListView1.SelectObjects(_MultiSelectList);
    objectListView1.EndUpdate();
}

// optional: to prevent flickering from the native item selection change, we freeze the OLV contents during the mouse click
private void objectListView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    objectListView1.Freeze();
}

private void objectListView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    objectListView1.Unfreeze();
}
```

Comment: Done. But I am a newbie here and the reputation is less than 15, so I could not give an up-vote for now. By the way, is there an easy way to unselect the last one row in the selected rows? It is easy to unselect the rows in the "_MultiSelectList" for other rows, but when I unselect the last one by clicking the row, it highlight again.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the attribute of ObjectListView or not

Comment: @Kevin.Yang: Hmm you are right about de-selecting the last row. I am not exactly sure why it is happening, but somehow the left-click seems processed despite the OLC being still "freezed". However you can work around that by setting `objectListView1.Activation = ItemActivation.TwoClick;`. This will prevent the normal row selection.